# What major threshhold did we just pass this week?

Tags: discussion

Okay.  Disingenuous question.  I just saw something really cool on http://www.quantcast.com/christianity.stackexchange.com

I'm looking at the number of unique people visiting the site, on a per week basis.  We are on a definite trend upward, but here's the really cool thing about this week.

This week, we have the highest number of unique visitors.  Ever.

We just surpassed the initial flurry of activity that was the beta!

I am psyched.

Comment: Traffic is still going up!

Answer (score 3):

Here's something cool - our *normal, daily traffic* is about where we were at that super-peak when everybody just found out about us!

Personally, I prefer weekly, since the weekends are really low for us.

[image: Look at our stats]

Answer (score 2):

Cool stats, and yes our traffic has been growing. Checking those interpolated numbers from a third party against the official ones on SE servers, I'm pretty sure we haven't actually quite hit that threshold yet although there is no denying that general trend. How you average weeks (particularly which days you start and end a week on) might also affect that number.

I hope this trend keeps up!